# How to keep open a file in mutiple functions python

Tags: python

Hey I would like to know how do I keep open :
`open(namefile + ".py", 'w')` in multiple fonctions , like :

```
invalid_inputCHOICE = True
invalid_inputCHOICE2 = True


def start():
    invalid_inputCHOICE = False
    print('creating file')
    with open("Hello World.txt", 'w') as f:
        f.write('Hello\n')
        world()



def world():
    invalid_inputCHOICE2 = False
    Answer = input('Should I write World ?')
    if Answer == 'yes':
        f.write('world')
    if Answer == 'no':
        print('Okay')
    else:
        print('please enter yes or no')
        world()

while invalid_inputCHOICE:
    start()
while invalid_inputCHOICE2:
    world()
```

and I got error : f is not defined but I defined it up .
So how can I do to fix this but keep my functions ?
error logs :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/PYTHON-WORKSPACE/FileCreations.py", line 26, in <module>
    start()
  File "H:/PYTHON-WORKSPACE/FileCreations.py", line 10, in start
    world()
  File "H:/PYTHON-WORKSPACE/FileCreations.py", line 23, in world
    world()
  File "H:/PYTHON-WORKSPACE/FileCreations.py", line 18, in world
    f.write('world')
NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

Comment: Even if `f` were in scope in `world`, `f` is closed as soon as you leave the `with` block, so you wouldn't be able to write to it anyways. The simple answer is to pass `f` into `world` as an argument, and return `f` from `start`.

Comment: Also, note that your global `invalid_inputCHOICE` and `invalid_inputCHOICE2` will always be `True` throughout the program.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the global keyword to make the scope of the f variable global :

```
invalid_inputCHOICE = True
invalid_inputCHOICE2 = True

with open("Hello World.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write('Hello\n')

def start():
    global f    # making the scope of the f varible global
    invalid_inputCHOICE = False
    print('creating file')
    world()

def world():
    global f    # making the scope of the f varible global
    invalid_inputCHOICE2 = False
    Answer = input('Should I write World ?')
    if Answer == 'yes':
        f.write('world')
    if Answer == 'no':
        print('Okay')
    else:
        print('please enter yes or no')
        world()

while invalid_inputCHOICE:
    start()
while invalid_inputCHOICE2:
    world()
```

Comment: Using ``global`` is inappropriate here. When ``start`` calls ``world``, it can just pass in ``f`` as a parameter. When ``world`` is called separately, ``f`` is already closed and should not be used. Passing the file around via ``global`` only obscures this bug.

Comment: Hi @MisterMiyagi, Of course passing `f` as argument would work, but question was about using `f` in multiple functions. So instead of passing `f` argument to multiple functions and keeping track of them, we can use a single variable with global scope avoiding multiple local scope variables.

Comment: We can, but those of us with experience of languages like FORTRAN II (back in 1968 ...) where global variables were the main way to communicate among modules have learned the pitfalls by bitter experience. Also, if for any reason the sequence of those calls changes so `world` is called before `start` you'll get an `UnboundLocalError`. Reasons such as this are why it's nowadays generally considered poor design to use global variables unless no alternative can be found. Modularity, coupling and encapsulation are all relevant terms here.

Comment: @ShubhamPathak As pointed out, even leaving aside code quality passing ``f`` as a ``global`` is plain wrong. ``f`` is *not* a writeable file object once ``start`` finishes. It fails to "**keep open** a file in multiple functions". The only reason why this is not directly apparent is that the code has another issue, ironically also by mishandling globals - the global ``invalid_inputCHOICE`` is never to False, only the local one inside ``start``, thereby never reaching the second loop.